# iPhone X sync never completes

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization

Whenever I place my iPhone X running 15.5 next to my Mac Pro running 12.4, it attempts to do a sync - as expected. Unfortunately, it never completes and leaves the system busy forever. This occurs over WiFi or on a cable. This is what I get...

[image: never ending sync]

It has been barber poled for an hour now. Any suggestions on...

1. what might be happening
2. what to force-quit to stop it?

Comment: Have you tried waiting it out, overnight if necessary?

Comment: Have you tried manually doing a sync or backup instead of waiting for the auto sync routine? What happens then? Has it worked before, and suddenly stopped?

Comment: Yes to both questions. The first I left running for an entire day and night. It never did anything other than barber pole. The second, if you mean pressing the button to sync, yes, it does the same thing.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I should also note that clicking "Skip Backup" does nothing.

Comment: You're probably going to have to wipe it & set up again. I've seen similar weirdness before & once it's decided it ain't gonna work, nothing will persuade it. If your computer backup prior to this one is too old [or in case it doesn't work], make sure your iCloud one is bang up to date. It might be worth clearing your MobileSync folder, or copying to a safe location first & giving it one last try.